# Checking data sent in http post Request

Tags: objective-c, http, post, logging

Is it possible to check the data which I have sent in HTTP POST request, by logging the request in XCode.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Firstname=%@&Lastname=%@&Email=%@",firstName,lastName,emailId];

NSLog(@"%@", post);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abcde.com/xyz/login.aspx"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



[request setHTTPBody:postData];

**NSLog(@"%@", request );**


NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I am logging the request as shown above in Bold. But here I am able to see only my Url and not any post data.

If it is not possible to see data here where can I see the data sent in http request.

Comment: You mean `NSLog(@"PostData: %@", request. HTTPBody);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just check what data are you sending then I suggest you to use this awesome tool http://www.charlesproxy.com. It's very simple and powerful. 
Just run Charles and do your request via simulator.